# Marionette - initialize event not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm have a basic Marionette app that looks like:

```
var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.on('initialize:after', function () {
    console.log('init');
});

App.start();
```

When I run this nothing gets printed to the console. However, if I add

```
App.on('start', function () {
    console.log('start');
});
```

then it prints `start`. Does anyone know how to get the former to work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Which version of marionette are you using?

`initialize:after` has been renamed to `start` after version 1.0.0. See the [changelog](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/changelog.md#v100-rc1-view-commit-logs).

Comment: I was using 2.0.1 -- but a much older tutorial apparently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Marionette 3, the events that are currently triggered, are:

- `"before:start"` / `onBeforeStart`: fired just before the Application starts and before the initializers are executed.
- `"start"` / `onStart`: fires after the Application has started and after the initializers have been executed.

---

```
var MyApp =  ContactManager = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

MyApp.on("before:start", function(options){
    options.moreData = "Yo dawg, I heard you like options so I put some options in your options!";
});

MyApp.on("start", function(options){
    console.log(options)
    /*
        if (Backbone.history){
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    */
});
```